# How to toggle the last two childs of ListItem using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having the list item which have some childs like..

```
  <li id="li1">Your Text 
      <a id="link1" href="#">click to enter</a>
      <input type="text" id="textbox1" value=""/>
      <input type="button" id="button1" value="Edit" />
   </li>
```

I want to hide and show the textbox and button when i click the link..

Please Help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this

```
$('#link1').click(function(){
    $('#li1').children().slice(-2).toggle();
});
​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QF44J/2/)

Comment: you can just do slice(-2) to get the last two :)

Comment: thanks.. Its works fine.. its hide and show only the last two childs.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#idOfList li a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings().toggle();
    });
});
```

The above assumes that you have something similar in each li element and you want to do the same action for all of them - for that to work you'd obviously put the id from the containing ul or ol element where I've said `"#idOfList"`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/j8NrE/

To do it *only* for the specific link with `id="link1"` just change the `"#idOfList li a"` selector to `"#link1"`.

Answer (score 1):

By using jQuery [**.siblings()**](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) and [**.slideToggle()**](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) methods you can achieve it easily by the following lines of code:

**jQuery:**

```
$(".list-item a").on("click", function(event){           
    $(this).siblings().slideToggle();
    event.preventDefault();    
});​
```

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li class="list-item">Your Text 
        <a id="link1" href="#">clike to enter</a>
        <input type="text" id="textbox1" value=""/>
        <input type="button" id="button1" value="Edit" />
    </li>

    <li class="list-item">Your Text 
        <a id="link2" href="#">clike to enter</a>
        <input type="text" id="textbox2" value=""/>
        <input type="button" id="button2" value="Edit" />
    </li>
</ul>​
```

### [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/LG44d/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#link1').click(function () {
            $('#textbox1').toggle();
            $('#button1').toggle();
        });
    });
</script>
```

See it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/LC7LT/2/

Comment: thanks for ur rply.. i want to hide both the button and textbox. And also when click again it should show..

Comment: He want's to be able to toggle them to hide/show on each click